# VBA SMTP Libraries

Tags: smtp

Does anyone know of any SMTP libraries that I can put directly into MS Access as a class module that does not rely on the Winsock dll or ocx or any other third party products?

We are currently using the SendObject functionality in MS Access but that is interfering with the Access runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for at:

http://www.worksrite.com/CDOMail.htm